# Sending POST data from actionscript 3.0 to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, http-post

I have a actionscript game that send data to a php with POST.
But I don't know how to make it working, first to get the data in php then to insert in database.

Here is the ActionScript, a part from game that send the post to php.

```
 public function post()
    {
        var _loc_1:* = new ByteArray();
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(1);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.u);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.r);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.t);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.p);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.apples);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.calories);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.StartTime);
        var _loc_2:* = 0;
        while (_loc_2 < this.moves.length)
        {

            _loc_1.writeShort(this.moves[_loc_2]);
            _loc_2 = _loc_2 + 1;
        }
        var _loc_3:* = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        var _loc_4:* = new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/Game.php");
        _loc_4.requestHeaders.push(_loc_3);
        _loc_4.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        _loc_4.data = _loc_1;
        var _loc_5:* = new URLLoader();
        _loc_5.load(_loc_4);
        _loc_5.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.PostCallback);
        return;
    }// end function

    public function PostCallback(param1)
    {
        this.tf.text = "PHP:" + param1.currentTarget.data;
        return;
    }// end function
```

Somewhere is the this.post();(is used when game is finished and win)

This is the data what i want to get in php, is like a scores:

```
var _loc_1:* = new ByteArray();
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(1);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.u);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.r);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.t);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.Args.p);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.apples);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.calories);
        _loc_1.writeUnsignedInt(this.StartTime);
```

Page Game.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbbg = 'pass';


mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbbg)or error("Could not connect:     ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or error(mysql_error());
if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA))
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO game (gameinfo) VALUES ('".$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA."');");
}
?>
```

It insert me in database a text like with nonsense characters.. 'YPDèU"ˆ†U"~µIk€†œ«¹ãV„–' 
I am appreciate any hand of help.

Comment: another route would be communication thru JSON

Comment: I am beginner , you can be more explicitly ?

Comment: i can't give a definitive answer but in one of my projects, one of my team mates (actionscript dev) sends me a JSON string instead, PHP consumes it  then decodes it

Comment: ok, I waiting for somewhat helpful response. Thankyou for your response.

Comment: sorry, can't give a script, i wasn't assigned to any actionscript part of that particular project thats why i never learned lol :D. but of course most likely this has already been done before, try to research some, that project was a long time ago so most likely there's already a lot of tutorials by then.

Comment: I already searched , almost all day , but I could not make it work ..and decided to ask here because it may be someone who will give me a helping hand. If you find something helpful here, you can post link .

Comment: Do you even know what you are doing there? It looks like decompiled code. Why would you even listen for a callback if you send no callback?

Comment: All I want to do is to save in database this.Args.u, this.Args.r, this.Args.apple, this.Args.calories, this.Args.StartTime. These are the kind of score.

Comment: You are saving them. The "nonsense" string is the binary string made of your values.

Comment: And how to decode this binary string  to real values ?